# IP Address auto change or use from a range of IP addresses

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dns, ip

Please help me find a way to tell `control.sys` file to read from a list of IP addresses or use a range to establish a connection for an application, instead of setting to a single IP address.

I am using a dynamic IP address, and often have to change the IP Address. I know changing to static would solve this, however some environments don't allow static IP addresses.

```
[Database]
Server=10.198.42.48
Path=10.198.42.48
```

The database for the application is stored on the local host, and shared to workstations. Should the Server IP Address, the workstations are no longer to connect without me having to manually change it.  I would like to instruct the file to use IP address from eg: 10.0.0.2 to 10.0.0.20 to establish an internet connection to the application

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If you cannot control the IP address how do you control the range it may be in? It might be worth looking at arp or similar to find the machine name; or initiate comms from the other end.

Comment: Welcome to SU. The question indeed could be better formulated, and more details would help us help you resolve the issue. What's "control.sys" in the first place? What OS are we talking about? What's the application? Commonly IP addresses in a network are pretty static even when configured with DHCP due to how DHCP servers work, so why exactly do you need to change your IP so often?